# Can you close the entry gate from outside the entry area?

Tags: the-witness

Here's the situation:

I've opened the gate out of the entry area, and I know the code to lock it again. But I want to see what it looks like from the other side when the "alternate exit" is available.

So I've left the entry area, come back in on the walls, and can see the gate. And normally you can manipulate any panel you can see (and from the walls I can work other puzzles in that area), but the gate panel won't activate for me.

Am I missing something, or is this an exception to the normal rules?